# Make a call graph at run-time for a specific method

Tags: c#, reflection

Say you have two simple interfaces and their methods:

```
ISerializable.Serialize(IValueWriter writer)
IValueWriter.WriteInt32(Int32 value)
IValueWRiter.WriteInt64(Int64 value)
```

When a class implements `ISerializable` I would like to be able to know which calls are made to the `IValueWriter` inside the `ISerializable.Serialize(IValueWriter writer)` implementation and generate a call graph from that. All of this needs to be done at run-time using reflection and **without calling the Serialize method** and it will be done also on classes which I have no control over as far as the code inside them goes.

Example:

```
public sealed class SomeObject : ISerializable
{
    private readonly Int32 first;
    private readonly Int64 second;

    public SomeObject(Int32 first, Int64 second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public void Serialize(IValueWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteInt32(this.first);
        writer.WriteInt64(this.second);
    }
}
```

The call graph would be:

```
SomeObject -> Serialize | -> IValueWriter.WriteInt32
                        | -> IValueWriter.WriteInt64
```

How would one accomplish this in a nice and clean fashion?
What I am truly aiming for is basically a `MethodInfo[]` of the calls made in a specific implementation of an interface method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using reflection.  I wouldn't really call it "runtime" when none of the code being analyzed is running.

1. Iterate all types in the assembly.
2. Filter for types implementing `ISerializable`
3. Find the method implementing `ISerializable.Serialize`
4. Fetch the IL
5. Look for `callvirt` instructions where the method token matches a method within `IValueWriter`.

There's an open source project, ILSpy, which should be a good example of how to decode IL instructions and look for method calls.

Comment: I figured this out after hacking away at it for a bit. Basically you're correct. I essentially took the MethodInfo from the Type and then played with MethodBody and MethodInfo.GetMethodBody. I built a reverse lookup table by reflecting out the OpCodes fields for the OpCode structures to decode their numeric values into their respective structures. I'll mark your answer as the solution since it's pretty much what I discovered in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

cleanest way is AOP.
take a look to [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)

All you need to do is to create some Attributes and add them to your methods, to be logged, etc.

as far as I know they manipulate the IL after compilation.

Comment: The methods need to be analyzed and call graphs made prior to their actual execution. Unfortunately, this won't work.

Comment: "The methods need to be analyzed and call graphs made prior to their actual execution" this is what will be done exactly. on calling a method which has a MethodStartAttribute, your code will be called

Comment: PostSharp won't help here.  Yes, it weaves your AOP, but it will do nothing for compile-time call graph analysis.